# Why does changing the size portion of the bootstrap row class make no difference in output?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

In my Meteor app, I'm experimenting with using the Bootstrap grid system. I added the twbs:bootstrap package and then this code, based on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_stacked_to_horizontal.asp).

```
  {{> bootstrapper}}
</body>

<template name="bootstrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World (sm)!</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Hello World! (sm-fluid)</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World (xs)!</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World (md)!</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Hello World (lg)!</h1>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
</template>
```

The conundrum is that they all display the same on my laptop (with the exception of the second one, which uses the "container-fluid" class instead of the "container" class, which monopolizes the entire width of the device):

[image]

I'm not quite grasping the concept of different sizes, anyway, as I thouht the whole, or at least the main, point of the bootstrap grid system was to make the page responsive, so that it will automatically adjust to screen size, whether that is xs, sm, md, or lg. So, why are these designations necessary, and why do they not seem to have any effect anyway?

### UPDATE

Okay, I see that these size class can be combined, like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 1</p></div>
```

...and thus I assume you can simply prepare for *all* contingencies (device sizes), like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 1</p></div>
```

...but that still makes me wonder what the point is, then - if you have to specify it all, where is the automagicality of bootstrap?

### UPDATE 2

With this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World (md)!</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color:red;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:green;">
      <p>Third 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:blue;">
      <p>Fourth 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:purple;">
      <p>Fifth 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...if I change the size of the browser window, it will either put each column on its own row, or all columns on a single row (there are either 1 or five columns, no in-between). I'm not sure just what that gives me other than not using bootstrap at all...

This is also true if I change the class from "container" to "container-fluid" So at this point I'm definitely wondering what all the hoopla is about.

I mean, I get that using the class names with numbers that add up to 12 are an easy way to layout a grid (using any combination of widths that add up to 12, such as 12 1s, 6 2s, 4 3s, or [1,2,3,4,2] or [1,9,2] or anything else), but I'm not seeing how it helps with responsive repositioning of the grid contents - unless settling for one row or twelve is really all it does. And so I don't see what added value the "xs", "sm", "md" or "lg" designators/breakpoints give me.

### UPDATE 3

Okay, I've got it now, after watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=no-Ntkc836w) - this is what y'all were telling me, but I guess I had to hear it and/or see it in action to grok it.

Comment: can you add JSFiddle with the related code please?

Comment: better to go to the bootstrap docs themselves and change your screen sizing there. Will see why

Comment: @North Dakota: it wouldn't be the same in jsfiddle, as it doesn't understand spacebars (Meteor), nor are the bootstrap classes built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3"><p>Box 1</p></div>`
>   ...but that still makes me wonder what the point is, then - if you
>   have to specify it all, where is the automagicality of bootstrap?

xs/sm/md/lg are called breakpoints. At certain points the layout changes. The magic is that you can decide exactly what widths the layout will hold, and when it should wrap, or even when it should hide.

lg affects all size, xs only effects the one smallest size.

Comment: I'm still not grokking it, because it all appears the same on my laptop no matter what breakpoints I give it. IOW, how would I get the columns to break onto another line with my device, which I assume is either md or lg?

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-12">Mobile 100% width and desktop 100% width</div><div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">All on new line: Mobile 100% width and desktop 50% width</div>`

Answer (score 2):

The col- classes are to do with when the columns will start to stack:

col-lg: Stack below 1200px width

col-md: Stack below 992px width

col-sm: Stack below 768px width

col-xs: Columns will never stack

edit: To develop on this a bit, the numbers after the classes (col-lg-12, col-sm-3 etc.) determine how many columns the div will occupy. In Bootstrap the document is comprised of 12 columns so you could have a col-lg-9 and a col-lg-3 and together they would occupy the full width of the page.

```
<div class="col-lg-9"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3"></div>
```

This would lead to the 'col-lg-9' div taking up the left-hand 75% of the page while the 'col-lg-3' div would take up the right-hand 25% of the page.

Since they are col-lg if the screen width were below 1200px the columns would move to stack on top of each other with the latter div moving below the former one at which point they would both take up the full width of the screen.

In another situation such as:

```
<div class="col-lg-9"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

Above 1200px this would behave exactly the same as the previous example however below this it will be different. When the screen width is below 1200px the 'col-lg-9' div will move to take up the full width of the screen and the 'col-md-3' div will move below it however it will still only occupy 25% of the screen until you move below the 992px breakpoint where it will then stretch to occupy the full screen.

Comment: So what effect do the numbers have? What is their raison-detre?